# Do you know the stress-strain-temperature equations?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, stress-strain, displacement

The case is that there are 3 layers which are bonded to adhesive joint.
And there are the stress-strain-temperature equations.
However I cannot understand what do these 3 equations mean.
The left side $\frac{du}{dx}$ means strain??
The last term $\alpha T$ may mean thermal expansion.
But $F/Et$ means which strain?

You can see the whole paper in this link,
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3b90/ea84e77216f69508777fcad3b51c5f6306ea.pdf

[image]

[image]

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 0):

The left side is indeed the total strain, and the alpha term is indeed the strain which would exist in the layer if it were free to change length without being constrained.  The difference between these is equal to the strain relative to the new stress free state at the new temperature.  So F/t is the tensile stress within the layer, and E is the Young's modulus of the layer.  The equation says that $\frac{F}{t}=E\left(\frac{du}{dx}-\alpha T\right)$

This is how Hooke's law has to be modified to include thermal expansion.

Comment: Thank you for explain. I couldn't have understood these equations without your explain. I have one more question about F/t. 
Tensile stress is the force divided by area, and how F/t can be tensile stress? Shouldn't we need to divide F by A?  If you let me know, I will be really grateful for you.

Comment: I assume F is force per unit width into the paper.